# Coadjoint orbit method (geometric quantization) for second quantisation of free relativistic particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, representation-theory, second-quantization, poincare-symmetry

The quantum theory for relativistic particles can be obtained by constructing the (projective) unitary irreducible representations associated to the integral coadjoint orbits of the Poincare group.
The $(m>0, s=0)$ orbit corresponds to the representation of the Poincare group that acts on solutions to the Klein-Gordon equation, the $(m=0, s=1/2)$ corresponds to the representation of the Poincare group acting on solutions to the massless Dirac equation etc.
For more details on this see [Geometric quantization](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/geometric-quantization-9780198502708?cc=gb&lang=en&) chapter 6.

These representations can be equipped with a symplectic form, so they can be viewed as infinite dimensional symplectic manifolds. We can then "second quantize" these orbits (construct pre-quantum line bundle and pick out a polarization) to obtain the corresponding irreducible unitary representations (quantum field theories).

**My question is**: *Does there exist an infinite-dimensional group whose coadjoint orbits correspond to the symplectic manifolds that we obtain from the representations of the Poincare group?*

So for instance one of the coadjoint orbits of this group should be a symplectic manifold isomorphic to the symplectic manifold of the classical Klein-Gordon field. I'm aware that for any of these classical theories I can just take the group of symplectomorphisms of the corresponding symplectic manifolds, however that would give me a different group for each free relativistic quantum field theory. I want a single group that can construct all of them.

The closesest reference I could find on this topic is Woit's [QFT and representation theory](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/sketch.pdf) paper.